# How to combine prototypes from closed functions?

Tags: javascript

Having a project where I have speed coded up some core functionality I would like to split it up into modules. My struggle now is how to combine prototypes from one to the next. My idea is something like this:

```
(function (window) {
    /* Code for base module with core functions. */
    function CORE () {

    }
    window.CORE = CORE; /* I use different naming in real code ... */

})(window);

(function (CORE) {
    /* Code for module with extending functionality. */
    function MODULE1 () {

    }
    CORE.MODULE1 = MODULE1;

})(window.CORE);
```

I use an approach for creation as something like:

```
(function (window) {

var Core = function (options) {
    return new Core.prototype.init(options);
}

Core.prototype = {
    init : function (options) {
        this.a = options.a;
        return this;
    }
}

Core.prototype.init.prototype = Core.prototype;

Core.prototype.init.prototype.fun1 = function () { }
Core.prototype.init.prototype.fun2 = function () { }
...

window.Core = Core;   /* Optionally = Core.init   */

})(window);
```

And then a module like:

```
(function (Core) {

var Module1 = Core.Module1 = function (options) {
    return new Module1.prototype.build(options);
}

Module1.prototype = {
    build : function (options) {
        this.a = options.a;
        return this;
    }
}

Module1.prototype.build.prototype = Module1.prototype;

Module1.prototype.build.prototype.fun1 = function () { }
Module1.prototype.build.prototype.fun2 = function () { }
...

Core.Module1    = Module1;
Core.Module1_XO = Module1.prototype.build;

})(window.Core);
```

Now a print of `toString()` of `Core`, `Core.Module1` and `Core.Module1_XO` all yield their respective code. But there is no binding as in:

If I say:

- `var obj = Core({...});` , OK.
- `obj.Module1({...})`, Fail. `Object #<Object> has no method Module1`
- `new obj.Module1_XO({...})`, Fail. `undefined is not a function`
- `Core.Module1({...})`, OK, but looses prototypes from Core.
- `new Core.Module1_XO({...})`, OK, but looses prototypes from Core.
- ...

---

One way that seem to work is by updating Core by a bind function as in:

```
var obj = Core({...});
var mod1 = Core.Module1({...}, obj); <-- pass obj

// In Module1 constructor:

build : function (options, ref) {
    this.a = options.a;
    ref.bind("Module1", this);
}

// And In Core:

Core.prototype.bind(which, what) {
    this[which] = what;
}
```

---

Question is how I can update `Core` with `Module` without this hack. Why doesn't `Core` become updated by:

```
window.Core.Module1 = Module1;
```

Is it hidden from Core?

I have also tried to bind in outer scope of module as in:

```
(function (Core) {

  /* ... code ... for Mudule1 */

   Core.bind("Module1", Module1);

}(window.Core);
```

But this fails as well. Core does not get updated with methods from Module.

[Here is a scramble of a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zquilch/rTa7k/2/) I have messed with, (*Note that the printed text is in reverse (prepended) not appended such as newest on top.*). It is not the most tidy code, and It is in midts of edits. (I try new approaches frequently.)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing right now is problematic for several reasons:

- You're adding a module to the constructor (type) and not the objects.
- Global state here - everyone gets *one* Module1.

My suggestion would be using a generic version of the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (or even a mediator).

Here is what it might look like.

```
Core = (function Core(){
    var modules = [];
    return {
        setModule : function(name,value){ 
            modules.push({name:name,value:value});
        },
        build     : function(options){
             this.a = options.a;
             // now let's add all modules
             modules.forEach(function(module){
                 this[module.name] = new module.value();
             });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage would be something like:

```
var app = new Core.build({a:"foo"});
app.a;//"foo"
```

If you want to add a module it'd be something like

```
 function Module1(){
     this.name = "Zimbalabim";
 }
 Core.setModule("Module1",Module1);
 var app = new Core.build({a:"Bar"});
 app.Module1.name;//"Zimbalabim"
 app.a;//"Bar"
```

Or course, a more generic architecture would allow creating different apps with different architectures (with dependency injection containers probably) but let's not go that far yet :)

Comment: Yes, looks sound. I have to see if I can make it fit. Going to hack on it in a moment. But I'm not sure why "everyone gets one Module1". I specify *Core* as the receiver... (And as it stands it seems like none gets one ;))